# Subcaption outside box environment - Align subcaption and table width

Tags: tables, align, subcaption, width

I am trying to align the width of my subcaption text below a table to the table width.
I use \scalebox and \input to adjust the size of the table.
However, my text below the table is wider than the table itself and I don't know how to align the text to the table width.
Do you have any ideas how to do that?
I always get the warning message ''Package caption Warning: \subcaption outside box or environment''.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularht}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=footnotesize, labelformat=empty, position=top]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering{
        \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
                \vspace{0.1cm}
        \label{tab:DesriptiveStatistics}
  }
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Median} & \textbf{Std. Dev.} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Whole Sample} &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    Profit & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
    Sales & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
    \textbf{A} &       &       &       &  \\
    Profit & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
    Sales & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
        \vspace{0.1cm}
\subcaption{This table shows the descriptive statistics for the whole sample as well as for the different sub-samples.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We haven't your file "descriptive statistic" Please, polute your table code with content from this file.

Comment: You are misusing `\subcaption`. It is meant to be used to add captions to subtables/subfigures, not for adding additional captions to a table/figure. That is what the warning is about (`\subcaption` is meant to be used inside a `subtable` or `subfigure` environment). Why don't you add the desctiption to the table's `\caption`?

Comment: All of this is of course unrelated to restricting the (sub)caption's width.

Comment: I have updated my MWE with the table code. Sorry for not having done this right at the beginning. Can I use \caption and make the text still appear below the table? I prefer to have the description below the table. Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer that's similar to [the one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651456/5001) which @Bernard has posted, in that it employs the [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package.

A `threeparttable` environment has (up to) three formal components: a `\caption`, a `tabular` environment (a `tabularx`, `tabulary`, or `tabular*` environment will do too) with any associate free-floating text (if any), and a `tablenotes` environment (to provided the footnote text associated with any `\tnote` directives placed inside the `tabular` environment.

What's special about the `threeparttable` environment is that it automatically restricts the widths of the caption, the `tablenotes` material, and any "free floating" text to that of the `tabular` environment.

Oh, and don't overdo it with **bold-facing** the contents of the header cells. A well-designed table generally doesn't need such visual stimulus at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% I've stripped down the preamble to the bare minimum
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %% that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % optional
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}
\label{tab:DesriptiveStatistics}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l cccc @{}}
\toprule
Variables & $N$ & Mean & Median & St.\ Dev. \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Whole Sample}  \\
Profit & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
Sales & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
\addlinespace

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Subsample A}  \\
Profit & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
Sales & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip\small % or "\footnotesize"
This table shows the descriptive statistics for the whole sample as well as for various subsamples.
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way uses the `threeparttable` environment, which measures the table width for table notes:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{dcolumn}
    \usepackage{tabularht}
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=footnotesize, labelformat=empty, position=top]{subcaption}
    \usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering\captionsetup{skip=1ex}%{
            \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
            \label{tab:DesriptiveStatistics}
      %
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Median} & \textbf{Std. Dev.} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Whole Sample} & & & & \\
        \midrule
        Profit & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
        Sales & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
        \textbf{A} & & & & \\
        Profit & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
        Sales & XXX & XXX & XXX & XXX \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
            \vspace{0.1cm}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[]\hskip -0.4em This table shows the descriptive statistics for the whole sample as well as for the different sub-samples.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

Since you not provide table contents, I assume that numbers have three digits as is shown in above picture. Real number you need to write yourself. If they have more digits, you need correct `S` columns specifications accordingly.

For table is used `talltblr`, a `tabularray` equivalent  for `threeparttable`. It enables to write captions and table notes or remarks as part of table, which widths are equal to table width. In MWE is used `tabularray` package version 2022C:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelformat=empty, position=top]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Descriptive Statistics},
  label = {tab:DesriptiveStatistics},   
 note{} = {This table shows the descriptive statistics for the whole sample as well as for the different sub-samples.}
                    ]{colspec={l
                               Q[c, si={table-format={3.0}}]
                          *{3}{Q[c, si={table-format={1.2}}]}},
                     row{1,2}={font=\bfseries, guard},
                     }
    \toprule
Variables   & N     & Mean  & Median& Std. Dev. \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=5]{l, font=\bfseries}    Whole Sample
            &       &       &       &           \\
text        & 123   & 1.23  & 1.23  & 1.23      \\ 
text        & 123   & 1.23  & 1.23  & 1.23      \\
\SetCell[c=5]{l, font=\bfseries}    A
            &       &       &       &           \\
text        & 123   & 1.23  & 1.23  & 1.23      \\
text        & 123   & 1.23  & 1.23  & 1.23      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```